# Enable Verbose Logging in SOAPpy

Tags: python, logging, soappy

How does one enable some sort of verbose output and/or logging in a SOAPpy client? This is so that I can diagnose some rather odd issues that cause the web service call to block execution without any sort of exception or crash.

Answer (score -2):

`SOAPpy` is dead, try to find something else, if possible.

I hade the same problem two months ago. Anyway, the latest version can be found at https://github.com/kiorky/SOAPpy

Comment: Unfortunately, I am stuck with that code as it is in production and changing it to a different library at this stage is unfeasible.

Comment: There are 3 problems with your answer: 1- you did not provide anything helpful or add additional info. 2- you should not criticize others' works. 3- you have provided link to the github project which is obviously not required; since the questionnaire has worked with it already.